# Can't Upload Image Using CodeIgniter Error Showing My Filename not column on database

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hello Everone I Want to ask why i cannot upload my image on database, and when i want to upload why not showing my column name instead my picture file name The Error Is

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Avanza.jpg' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `upload` (`Avanza`.`jpg`) VALUES ('')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

And This My Code

For Controller

```
function file_data(){
      $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
      $config['max_size'] = '2048';  //2MB max
      $config['max_width'] = '4480'; // pixel
      $config['max_height'] = '4480'; // pixel
      $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['fotopost']['name'];

      $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!empty($_FILES['fotopost'])) {
            if ( $this->upload->do_upload('fotopost') ) {
                $foto = $this->upload->data();
                $data = $foto['file_name'];
                $this->upload_foto->save_pic($data);
              redirect('');
            }else {
              die("gagal upload");
            }
        }else {
          echo "tidak masuk";
        }
   }
```

And This For My Model

```
class Upload_foto extends CI_Model{

    function save_pic($data){

        $this->db->insert('upload',$data);

      }
  }
```

Thanks For The Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is telling you what is wrong here.

Basically its saying - I do not know a Column Name called "fluffybunny.jpg" (random file name chosen)

What it is expecting is a column name and a value.

**Assuming your** **Table Column name for your image files** is **file_name**, then your $data needs to be an array like...

```
$data['file_name'] = $foto['file_name'];
```

**So what you need to be inserting is an associative array ['field_name' => 'value']**

NOTE: It also pays "Bigtime" to read the CodeIgniter user Guide.